# Solving SHM using laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

SHM can be described as 
$$x''= -\omega^2x$$

If initial conditions are $x(0) = x_0,\ x'(0)=y_0$
I need to solve this equation by

a) Taking laplace transforms directly

b) Defining the function y(t) = x'(t) and hence obtaining an equivalent pair of coupled, first-order differential equations

I can do part a) where I got $x(t)=\frac{y_0}{\omega}\sin{(\omega t)} + x_0\cos{(\omega t)}$ but I am confused as to what to do for part b. I don't understand what it wants me to find.

Comment: In part $b)$, the author wants you to solve the system
\begin{align}
x' &= y \\
y' &= - \omega^{2} x
\end{align}
which is a [matrix ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Solved_example_of_a_matrix_ODE) of the form $z' = Az$, with initial conditions $y(0) = y_{0}, x(0) = x_{0}$.

Comment: I used your approach to find the solutions to $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$. Do you want to submit a proper answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we call $x'=y_1$ and $x''=y_1'=y_2$, then we can rewrite the ODE as a system:

$y_1'=y_2$

$y_2'=-\omega^2 y_1$

Can you cast this into a matrix form? Then you will need to find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$ of this matrix.
The solution of the system is then given by (if the eigenvalues are destinct)
$$Y=c_1v_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2v_2e^{\lambda_2 t}.$$

Note, that $Y=[y_1,y_2]^T$ is a vector.